# How to specify type of date format when importing csv into mongo

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoimport

How do I specify the date format when importing csv into mongo?

My date format is like this: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS

**field_file_types.txt**

```
id.auto()
created_timestamp.date(2022-06-19 09:06:30.49657)  # this doesn't work
```

**script.sh**

```
mongoimport --type csv --file ./latest.csv --columnsHaveTypes --fieldFile=./field_file_types.txt"
```

**latest.csv**

```
id,created_timestamp
14,2022-06-19 09:06:30.49657
```

> Error:  Failed: type coercion failure in document #0 for column 'created_timestamp', could not parse token 'created_timestamp' to type date

**Alternatively**

Can you advise the format that mongo will accept automatically as a date? And how do I specify it? Can you provide a simple example:  ie isodate etc...

Comment: You say "My date format is like this: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS" but in your sample  is `2022-06-19 09:06:30.49657` which is a different format

Answer (score 0):

You can add the option: [--columnHaveTypes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/?_ga=2.13995127.134876043.1655742655-1341466864.1641598014#std-option-mongoimport.--columnsHaveTypes)  and specify the column types as follow:

```
  mongoimport --db=users --collection=contacts --type=csv \
  --columnsHaveTypes \
  --fields="name.string(),birthdate.date(2006-01-02),contacted.boolean(),followerCount.int32(),thumbnail.binary(base64)" \
  --file=/example/file.csv
```

for example your file with types can look as follow:
field_file_types.txt

```
 id.auto(),created_timestamp.date()
```

Check here posible format [options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/?_ga=2.13995127.134876043.1655742655-1341466864.1641598014#std-option-mongoimport.--columnsHaveTypes)

this looks like at least not throwing errors:

```
 CSV:2022-06-19 09:06:30.49657
 fields: dates.date_oracle(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS)
 imported: dates : ISODate("2022-06-19T09:06:30.496Z")
```

same with dates.date_oracle(YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS)

Comment: I think the date must be `id.auto(),created_timestamp.date(2006-01-02 15:04:05.000)` or `created_timestamp.date_oracle(YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS)` should also work.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : It seems you are right , just tested and this seems to work fine: --fields="id.auto(),dates.date_oracle(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS)"

Comment: I am still getting error type coercsion, could not parse token 'created_timestamp' to type date.  created_timestamp=2022-06-21 07:47:48
mongoimport  --uri "mongodb://user:passt@mongo1/db" -c todos --type csv --file /data/db/latest.csv --columnsHaveTypes --fields "id.auto(),todoText.string(),created_timestamp.date(2006-01-02 15:04:05),completed.date(2006-01-02 15:04:05)" --authenticationDatabase admin

Comment: Even with date_oracle() ?

Comment: Yep, even with oracle